# .classpath and .project not found

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have downloaded `apache-maven-3.2.5` from the official site...In addition I installed maven plugin through adding new software via `Help->install new software in Eclipse, juno. And in the windows preferences->Maven->the path mentioned is of the apache-maven-3.2.5`. Is this the correct way to install maven plugin in eclipse? I'm unable to find `.classpath` and `.project` files with in target folder when I create a new maven project.

Comment: Those should be in the project's root folder (hidden by eclipse).

Comment: @GáborBakos I think that qualifies as an answer, you may want to add it like that.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have installed the m2e plugin to eclipse. In that case the `.classpath` and `.project` files are created in the project's root folder, not within the `target` folder. You should look for them there (though those are hidden in most eclipse views).